# How does Flink runtime get task manager JVM metrics like 'Status.JVM.Memory.Heap.Used'?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

There has been a few blog posts that give introduction on the high level design of Flink metrics reporting system. However, it is still not clear to me how JVM related metrics like 'Status.JVM.Memory.Heap.Used' are collected.

I have tried to find that in Flink source code. MemoryLogger.java seems do some work on getting JVM related metrics. https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/taskmanager/MemoryLogger.java#L88. However, it is still not clear how the metrics flows back to MetricsRegistry. Any pointers on that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Flink has a dedicated thread to collect system related metrics for each task manager.

System metrics are collected by  [SystemResourcesCounter](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/52e5d7c4fa479adbb48cf83a9f09d78978ddd8b7/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/metrics/util/SystemResourcesCounter.java)

JVM memory metrics can be accessed through `ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage()`

The code for getting JVM related metrics is in 
[MetricUtils.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/metrics/util/MetricUtils.java) in `flink-runtime` module.